# grub-mkimage - cannot open `/srv/tftp/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/core.efi.mod; how to resolve?

Tags: grub2

I am trying to build a new bootloader, regrettably without knowing too much about the subject. I'm following the instructions in [Problems booting installer to UEFI system via PXE](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/problems-booting-installer-to-uefi-system-via-pxe-4175696093/).

I first run:

```
grub-mknetdir --net-directory=/srv/tftp/ --subdir=/boot/grub
Netboot directory for x86_64-efi created. Configure your DHCP server to point to /srv/tftp/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/core.efi
```

This seemed to work, so I go on to the next command:

```
root@vogon:~# grub-mkimage -O x86_64-efi /srv/tftp/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/core.efi --prefix='tftp,192.168.50.9)/boot/grub' efinet tftp
grub-mkimage: error: cannot open `/srv/tftp/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/core.efi.mod': No such file or directory.
```

I can see the `.mod` files in `/srv/tftp/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/`:

```
root@vogon:~# file /srv/tftp/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/*
/srv/tftp/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/acpi.mod:                 ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
/srv/tftp/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/adler32.mod:              ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
/srv/tftp/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/affs.mod:                 ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
/srv/tftp/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/afs.mod:                  ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
...
```

The `efinet.mod` and `tftp.mod` both exist, but no `core.efi.mod`, of course. The `core.efi` file is different from the `.mod` files:

```
root@vogon:~# file /srv/tftp/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/core.efi
/srv/tftp/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/core.efi: PE32+ executable (EFI application) x86-64 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows
```

How do I get past this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, these commands should work to create boot images for bios and uefi hosted in the standard tftp directory.

```
apt-get install grub-pc-bin grub-efi-amd64-bin
mkdir -p /srv/tftp
grub-mknetdir --net-directory /srv/tftp/
```

If you use the verbose flag then you can see the `grub-mkimage` commands being used by `grub-mknetdir`.

```
# grub-mknetdir --net-directory /srv/tftp/ -v
...
grub-mknetdir: info: grub-mkimage --directory '/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc' --prefix '/boot/grub' --output '/srv/tftp/boot/grub/i386-pc/core.0'  --dtb '' --format 'i386-pc-pxe' --compression 'auto'  'tftp' 'pxe'
...
grub-mknetdir: info: grub-mkimage --directory '/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi' --prefix '/boot/grub' --output '/srv/tftp/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/core.efi'  --dtb '' --format 'x86_64-efi' --compression 'auto'  'tftp' 'efinet'
```

You could simply adapt these commands for your customizations

```
grub-mkimage --directory '/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi' --prefix '(tftp,192.168.50.9)/boot/grub' --output './core.efi' --format 'x86_64-efi' --compression 'auto'  'tftp' 'efinet'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
root@vogon:~# grub-mkimage -O x86_64-efi /srv/tftp/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/core.efi --prefix='tftp,192.168.50.9)/boot/grub' efinet tftp
```

You missed the `-o` option.

Instead of trying to *build* the core image as `/srv/tftp/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/core.efi` as you apparently intended, the command is assuming all non-option parameters are GRUB module names, and so it adds the `.mod` suffix and looks for `.../core.efi.mod` to incorporate it into the GRUB image, which would be outputted into standard output by default.

Try instead:

```
grub-mkimage -O x86_64-efi -o /srv/tftp/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/core.efi --prefix='tftp,192.168.50.9)/boot/grub' efinet tftp
```

You might also want to include the UEFI display driver modules `efi_gop` and `efi_uga`, to ensure that if something goes wrong, you'll at least be able to see the error message from GRUB.